# 1x1 convolutions vs reducing number of filters

Tags: computer-vision, deep-learning

In DNN architectures like GoogLeNet 1x1 convolutions are heavily used. I understand the reason to use them is mainly dimensionality reduction, i.e. if the previous convolutional layer had C channels, I can use a 1x1xC' convolution with C' < C to reduce the number of channels.

However, what is the advantage of doing this over reducing the number of filters in the previous layer in the first place? For example, in GoogLeNet there's a Max Pooling Layer that has C=480 output channels (and so does the layer before it). The Inception module (inception (4a)) that follows it uses three 1x1 convolutions with C'=192, 96, 16. Why not take C in the previous layer smaller to begin with, say 200 or 300? Of course, I'd still use the 1x1 convolutions to reduce the dimensions to the corresponding 3x3 and 5x5 filters.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% certain and I would always simply try it, but I have two educated guesses why you might want to have 1x1 convolutions instead of simply having less filters in the layer before:

- You add parameters and allow the network thus to find more complex combinations of the layers.
- The optimization problem might be simpler (thus the network could learn in fewer iterations)